# Stopping a loop that contains a SetTimeout with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have the following code:

```
  var sequencerRun = function(){    
  var currentTime = 0 
  var starting = 200

  for(var k = 0; k < 16; k++){
    $(".instrument td .beat" + k).each(function(){
      setTimeout(blinker, currentTime,$(this));
    })
    currentTime += starting
    }
  }

  var timerId;

  var runSeq = function(){
    setInterval(sequencerRun,3200);
  }

  $('.play').click(function(){
    sequencerRun();
    runSeq();
  })

  $('.stop').click(function(){
    //??????
  })
```

I am using this code as a way to run through my sequencer in a drum machine I am building. `sequencerRun` runs through a matrix, built using a `table`, and checks each column to see if it will play the corresponding sound. What I am doing is scheduling checks at each column(1 - 16) at different times (0,200,400,...,1600) respectively with `setTimeout(blinker, currentTime,$(this));`. The problem is that these events are scheduled right away on each invocation on `sequencerRun`. So if `sequencerRun` gets invoked and I click at time 850, I want all of the setTimeouts with times 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600 to not invoke `blinker`. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the interval in a `variable` and use [**clearInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

```
 var interval;
 var runSeq = function(){
    interval = setInterval(sequencerRun,3200);
  }

  $('.play').click(function(){
    sequencerRun();
    runSeq();
  })

  $('.stop').click(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
```

Also, for the `setTimeout` itself

```
setTimeout(blinker, currentTime,$(this));
```

use a **flag**

```
var stopped = false;
$('.stop').click(function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
        stopped = true;
      });
```

and in the *callback*

```
function blinker(){
   if(stopped){
       return;
   }
   //...else, continue normal execution
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(blinker, currentTime,$(this));` I want to stop the scheduled ones  being run through this setTimeout. I am editing the post now.

Comment: Hey, I have another question, stop and play can be clicked back and forth. When I click play then click stop blinker is invoked but isnt executed. The problem happens when I press play stop and then press play right away again the flag changes and I have two iterations running now. Any advice?

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst, in not sure if I fully understand you. Would your problem be solved if you wrapped `sequenceRun` with an `if` condition like `blink`? So `if(!stopped)`